# Use JVM Options in Maven Plugin to get rid of relative path dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, jvm-arguments

I've got a **project A** which consists of several modules. This is the "product" itself (server/client application). Furthermore there is another **project B** which is a specific customer project.

When the client+server *.jar of project A are assembled, resources of project B need to be integrated. I.e. copied into a resource folder.

I'm using the maven-resources-plugin to copy some of the property files:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>../../commonDashboard/src/main/resources/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>commonDashboard.*.properties</include>
                        <include>db.*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

This approach requires a relative dependency between both projects. I want to get rid of the relative path and use a path definition which is provided as VM Options in IntelliJ. So when running the assembly modules I need to access the VM options. I'm not quite sure if this is possible at all. I guess it's not, right? Do you know any other approach to get rid of this dependency between both projects? I don't want to add the options into the maven assembly file itself.

Comment: Usually, I wouldn't copy properties files from one project to another. Rather, I would make their content available through Java classes and define the project as a dependency.

Comment: The properties are overwritten in the customer project B with customer specific values I don't want to reconfigure the properties on every deployment. Project A contains properties with default values, which are used if none are defined in the customer project.

Comment: Doesn't project B create an artifact with the resources in?  Just use that as a dependency.

Comment: The assembly module, which is part of product A, takes the ressources of product A and project B and copies the properties into a resource folder. We need to stick to this approach. So refactoring is not an option at the moment. As mentioned above, I want to get rid of the relative path.